# does "bearing good or ill" here means "producing good or ill"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

does "bearing good or ill" here means "producing good or ill"?

> what is the meaning of vibration? a supernatural emanation, **bearing**
>   good or ill, that is sensed by or revealed to those attuned to the
>   occult.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/vibration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Bearing" literally means "carrying". When talking about something like "good" or "evil", it means that you are carrying these things in a figurative sense.

Your excerpt is saying that these "emanations" *bring* good, or ill will.